# Lua Text Loop on GMOD Server

Tags: loops, timer, lua

I want to make a box on GMOD where appears text and the text changes every 6 minutes. Here's what I've got so far:

```
    AddCSLuaFile( "classes.lua" );

surface.CreateFont( "mystyle", { 
font = "Arial",
    extended = false,
    size = 20,
    weight = 500,
    blursize = 0,
    scanlines = 0,
    antialias = true,
    underline = false,
    italic = false,
    strikeout = false,
    symbol = false,
    rotary = false,
    shadow = false,
    additive = false,
    outline = false,
}   );

function classesBox() -- Box thing function
draw.RoundedBox(3, 5, 250, 320, 100, Color(0,0,0,200));

end 
hook.Add("HUDPaint", "MyHudName", classesBox)


 while true do
--Infinite loop
 timer.Simple(50, function() draw.SimpleText("Text 1", "mystyle", 24, 275, Color(255,255,255,255)); draw.SimpleText("Text 2", "mystyle", 24, 300, Color(255,255,255,255)); end );

 end
```

On the client the text is not appearing and I don't know what to do...
Is there a way that Is more easy than what I'm doing? I'm kind of new with Lua and I'd appreciate any advice.

EDIT:**Also, I want it to play automatically on the server, so when I log in, I see the same text in the box as the other players. Right now I have it in the autorun folder, but whenever I log in it starts from the beginning :/
And I also want it to be repeating forever, but if I use a while loop it crashes my game.**

NOTE: I put the timer to 50 seconds just to test it

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to do it that way. Use a variable to decide if you want to draw it or not and use it inside HUDPaint.

```
function classesBox( )
  draw.RoundedBox( 3, 5, 250, 320, 100, Color( 0, 0, 0, 200 ) )
  if SomeCondition then
    draw.SimpleText( "Text 1", "mystyle", 24, 275, color_white )
    draw.SimpleText( "Text 2", "mystyle", 24, 300, color_white )
  end
end

SomeCondition = true
timer.Simple( 50, function( ) SomeCondition = false end )
```

A timer doesn't have the right context to use the rendering functions, and it would need drawn each frame instead of just once.